# ng-click is not working in salesforce 1 in iphone

Tags: community, salesforce1-app

i am using angular js to develope salesforce 1 app in iphone but when i click on submit button it do not call angular js function and focusing control to a drop down which i have on my page. strange...

Any help would be appreciated.

code:-

```
<div class="bootstrap" ng-app="ngApp" ng-controller="OpportunityCtrl">
<div class="col-md-12">
  <button ng-click="testmethod();" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
  <button ng-click="testmethod()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
```

javascript

```
var app = angular.module("ngApp", []); 
  app.controller("OpportunityCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
   <!-- Initialize Model Variables -->
    $scope.oppRequestObject = {};
    $scope.oppRequestObject.Name = ''; 
    $scope.isError = false;
    $scope.errorControl = ''; 

    $scope.testmethod = function() {
      alert('test method');
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: @SF_user posted.

Comment: Is this a mistake copying your code : `onclick="ng-click="testmethod();"` ?

Comment: @sf_user sorry..... 'ng-click="testmethod();"'

Comment: on my iphone its submitting all the time...even the type is button

Comment: Does it work in the desktop browser using one/one.app? You didn't post your entire code. It can be easy to incorrectly close the controller array parameter. Are you certain that you closed it as `}]);` (close function, close array, close parens for parameters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just because of css  `class="btn btn-default"` which are bootstrap classes and somewhere in the bootstrap JS it has referenced which causing button to submit every time.

This work in desktop browser with these classes but in Iphone these needs to be removed.

Thanks